# Map on Akka source: "... doesn't conform to expected type T_"

Tags: scala, types, stream, akka

I have the following code:

```
  override def factors: Source[MarketFactors, NotUsed] = {
    Source(Stream.continually(generator)).map(random => {
      val correlated = currentFactors.keys zip random.nextVector()

      val generatedPrice: Map[Equity, Double] = correlated.toSeq.map({
        case (equity, randomValue) =>
          (equity, currentFactors(equity).price + randomValue * currentFactors(equity).volatility)
      })(scala.collection.breakOut)

      GeneratedMarketFactors(generatedPrice)
    })
 }
```

It should take the value from the random generator and create a new price. 
The function given to map has the type `CorrelatedRandomVectorGenerator => MarketFactors`. `GeneratedMarketFactors` is declared as inner case class and extends `MarketFactors`.

However, I get the error `Expression of type FactorsGenerator.GeneratedMarketFactors doesn't conform to expected type T_`. What am I doing wrong?

I am not very happy with the mix between Scala and Akka streams, any replacement for the `Stream.continually(generator)`?

Comment: As for the Stream.continually question, you can use Source.repeat (if you use the same instance), Source.repeat(token).map(createGenerator) to create a new instance every time, or of course use Source.fromIterator(() => ...) if you can express it as an iterator. Source.unfold can be another option. Please look at the Source companion object for variants: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.171304800.1520294582.1409309043#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source$

Comment: As for the type error, I have no idea, without knowing more about your code I cannot really say anything. When I try your snippet with dummy implementation of the involved classes it compiles without issues.